# Django subquery outerref('id') You might need to add explicit type casts

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I'm using postgresql.
i write subquery in subquery i want to apply filter on `id` of parent table with field of child table. but it shows error

query:
`orders = Order.objects.filter(user=request.user, status='P')
albums = models.Album.objects.annotate(purchased_status=Subquery(orders.values('id').filter(item_id=OuterRef('id'))[:1]))`

Error
`django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: operator does not exist: character varying = integer
LINE 1: ...atus" = 'P' AND U0."user_id" = 1 AND U0."item_id" = "bookcen...
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.`

if i apply filter on any of field other then id it work fine. this error fix if i will add `id` for parent table as `foreign key` in child table but don't want to do this.

issue if because `OuterRef('id')` return reference id not just integer value like `1` or `2`
is there any way with which `OuterRef('id')` can return integer value of id.

Answer (score 1):

The [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/expressions/#django.db.models.OuterRef) read:

> Use OuterRef when a queryset in a Subquery needs to refer to a field
>   from the outer query.

The [relevant example](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/expressions/#subquery-expressions):

```
newest = Comment.objects.filter(post=OuterRef('pk')).order_by('-created_at')
Post.objects.annotate(newest_commenter_email=Subquery(newest.values('email')[:1]))
```

It is model `Comment` that has a ForeignKey to model `Post` and `newest` collects all `Comments` associated with each `Post` and sorts them from the most recent to the oldest.

From that `Subquery` the `email` column is selected and the first row is extracted to an attribute `newest_commenter` for each `Post` in the query.

Therefore, in your example assuming that `Order` has a foreignKey to `Album`you could do something like:

```
orders = Order.objects.filter(album=OuterRef('pk'), user=request.user, status='P')
models.Album.objects.annotate(purchased_status=Subquery(orders.values('id')[:1]))
```

This way for each `Album` you will receive an attribute `purchased_status` which will contain the `id` of the first `Order`, if the current user has made at least one `Order` with status `P`.

Comment: yes i understand by adding foreignKey it works.but i want to ask is there any way with which it can work without adding foreignKey?